# How is the system partition detected during startup?

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I have my mount point for `/` in my `/etc/fstab`. However, to read `/etc/fstab`, Ubuntu needs to know where `/` is. This sounds like a chicken or egg problem to me. How does Ubuntu do this?

Comment: grub knows about the `/` fs (sort of) - you don't want the details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As @ridgy says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877669/how-is-the-system-partition-detected-during-startup#comment1365072_877669), GRUB knows `/`:

```
$ grep -w vmlinuz /boot/grub/grub.cfg -m1
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-59-generic root=UUID=21ff70e8-39ce-432d-98cc-d45c50ed1265 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Note how GRUB passes the UUID of my root partition to Linux.

Related, on Unix & Linux:

- [How is /etc/fstab accessed before root is mounted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107828/70524)
- [Does initramfs use /etc/fstab?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92720/70524)